# Issue on opening project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I try to open project of my friend in Android Studio. He created it in Android Studio. I have archive with that contains this project. In Studio i clicked Fie->Open and there choose folder with project. But than i get error:

> UnsupportedMethodException
>            Failed to set up Android modules in project 'tissapp': Unsupported method: SourceProvider.getJniDirectories().
>            The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
>            To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
>            Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.

I use

> dependencies {
>
> ```
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'
> }
> ```

When i try to use newer virsion (such as ) i have new error in Event Log

> AssertionError: null

with details:

> null java.lang.AssertionError     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.PreSyncChecks.attemptToUpdateGradleVersionInWrapper(PreSyncChecks.java:174)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.PreSyncChecks.ensureCorrectGradleSettings(PreSyncChecks.java:72)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:53)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.doImport(GradleProjectImporter.java:430)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.doRequestSync(GradleProjectImporter.java:219)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.access$000(GradleProjectImporter.java:77)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter$2.run(GradleProjectImporter.java:184)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:77)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.requestProjectSync(GradleProjectImporter.java:191)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.requestProjectSync(GradleProjectImporter.java:166)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.editors.ProjectSyncStatusNotificationProvider$ProjectImportFailedNotificationPanel$1.run(ProjectSyncStatusNotificationProvider.java:104)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.EditorNotificationPanel$2.hyperlinkActivated(EditorNotificationPanel.java:88)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.HyperlinkAdapter.hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkAdapter.java:28)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.HyperlinkLabel.fireHyperlinkEvent(HyperlinkLabel.java:172)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.HyperlinkLabel.processMouseEvent(HyperlinkLabel.java:105)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)     at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4489)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Maybe i do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing the project, make sure you pick up the Gradle wrapper files that were part of that project (**gradlew**, **graadlew.bat**, and the **gradle** directory) and allow it to use the wrapper when importing the project. That will ensure that it has a compatible version of Gradle to run the project with.

The version number you listed:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'
}
```

isn't the version of Gradle itself, but the Android plugin for Gradle. The error message you're getting looks like a bad version of Gradle, but using the wrapper the right way should fix it.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. That was bad version of Gradle. I updated  Android Studio to latest version and build completed without errors. And now I am using `gradle:1.0.0-rc4`